# use specific python version in virtualenv (virtualenvwrapper) after creating the virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I would like to know if it is possible to specify the python version in a virtual environment (created with virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper) after the environment is created.

If I create a virtualenv with the following command:

`mkvirtualenv -p python3.8 venvname`

I would like to know:

I can be sure that I am using python3.8 by just typing `python` when the virtual environment is activated and it will display something like the following:

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more 
information.
>>>
```

The only way to specify the python version in the `mkvirtualenv` command is (as far as I know) to have python3.8 installed beforehand

Indeed, if for example I do

`mkvirtualenv -p python3.6 venvname`

I get the following error

`RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.6'`

since I don't have python3.6 installed.

My question is:

**Can I change the python version installed in my virtualenv after having created it?**

Thanks in advance to anyone who will try to help me.

Comment: Please ask one question per question only!

Comment: You are right, I am sorry about that. I edited the question to ask only one question. Now it should be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I be sure that I am using python3.6?

If you mean at runtime, `python --version` inside the venv should do it.

> Is the only way to specify the python path?

With mkvirtualenv I believe so.  With `python -m venv` the particular python executable you call sets up the venv.  ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/venv.html))

> Can I change the python version installed in my virtualenv after I create it?

AFAIK there is no built in way to do this.  It *is* possible just to replace the executable, update the libraries, and go, but this sounds like a recipe for disaster, quite aside from dimension changes.  Since you venv is presumably being used to develop a package, and since you keep your package dependencies somewhere---either a `requirements.txt` or a `setup.py` or something like that, make a new virtualenv with a new python and starting afresh should be straightforward.

Incidentally if you haven't already you might want to consider managing all this with `poetry`, which makes re-creating the venv even easier---just delete the venv dir and do `poetry install` again.

I'm willing to be proven wrong about updating python within a venv, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! after posting my question I figured out the first two questions out and then I was thinking that the third one did not make sense since, as you said, might be a recipe for disaster! 

I think that the only way I have to use `python3.6` is to have it installed on my local machine and then do `mkvirtualenv -p python3.6 venvname`

Comment: I think that this answer is what I was looking for in the end. I will accept it in few days if no one will prove the author wrong.